# Facebook App in Page Tab receiving signed_request but missing page data

Tags: authorization, facebook-page

I have a page tab app that I am hosting. I have both http and https supported. While I receive a signed_request package as expected, after I decode it does not contain page information. That data is simply missing.

I verified that like schemes are being used (https) among facebook, my hosted site and even the 'go between'-- facebook's static page handler.

Also created a new application with page tab support but got the same results-- simply no page information in the signed_request.

Any other causes people can think of?

I add the app to the page tab using this link:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=176236832519816&next=https://www.intelligantt.com/Facebook/application.html

Here is the page tab I am using (Note: requires permissions):

https://www.facebook.com/pages/School-Auction-Test-2/154869721351873?id=154869721351873&sk=app_176236832519816

Here is the decoded signed_request I am receiving:

{"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","code":!REMOVED!,"issued_at":1369384264,"user_id":"1218470256"}

5/25 Update - I thought maybe the canvas app urls didn't match the page tab urls so I spent several hours going through scenarios where they both had a trailing slash or not. Where they both had a trailing ? or not, with query parameters or not.

I also tried changing the 'next' value when creating the page tab to the canvas app url and the page tab url.

No success on either count.

I did read where because I'm seeing the 'code' value in the signed_request it means Facebook either couldn't match my urls or that I'm capturing the second request. However, I given all the URL permutations I went through I believe the urls match. I also subscribed to the 'auth.authResponseChange' which should give me the very first authResponse that should contain the signed_request with page.id in it (but doesn't).

If I had any reputation, I'd add a bounty to this.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the app id and app secret are set correctly? that´s usually the problem in this case. and are you using the php sdk? it´s a waste of time (and code) to do the encoding on your own, while there´s "getSignedRequest" in the php sdk.

Comment: I am using the javascript API and not the php sdk. I am 100% positive the app id is correct. App Secret I am not using becaase it is the javascript API. My understanding is the iframe and the accompanying javascript does receive a 'full' signed_request. This signed request is being parsed according to Facebook's specification: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/

Comment: Here is the Facebook documentation that makes me believe the iframe+javascript will receive the 'full' signed_request: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/                           From the doc-- "This means you can now build apps that run across Facebook (including Pages and Canvas applications) using the same simple, standards-based web programming model (HTML, JavaScript, and CSS)."

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem but on 2 domains. On domain 1 I'm getting page data with page ID in the signed request but on domain 2, I'm getting signed req without page data. Everything is same except the domain and facebook app (page tab url). I changed the url in the apps to the other domains but it still didn't work. I think it is because of the domain only that I'm not getting the page object on 1 of the domains and getting it on the other. Need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just spent ~5 hours on this exact same problem and posted a prior answer that was incorrect.  Here's the deal:

As you pointed out, signed_request appears to be missing the page data if your tab is implemented in pure javascript as a static html page (with *.htm extension).

I repeated the exact same test, on the exact same page, but wrapped my html page (including js) within a Perl script (with *.cgi extension)... and voila, signed_request has the page info.

Although confusing (and should be better documented as a design choice by Facebook), this may make some sense because it would be impossible to validate the signed_request wholly within Javascript without placing your secretkey within the scope (and therefore revealing it to a potential hacker).

Comment: Thank you yahermann, your diagnosis and solution is correct! Would have saved a tonne of time for both of us (and I presume others) if Facebook documented this security feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier with the PHP SDK, but if you just want to use JavaScript, maybe this will help:

[Facebook Registration - Reading the data/signed request with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827686/facebook-registration-reading-the-data-signed-request-with-javascript)

Also, you may want to check out this: https://github.com/diulama/js-facebook-signed-request

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't believe it's an issue with parsing the signed_request. Rather, it seems like some configuration requirement is not being met and as a result the signed_request simply doesn't have the page information.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can't get the full params with the javascript signed_request, use the php sdk to get the full signed_request . and record the values you need into javascript variabls ...

with the php sdk after instanciation ... use the facebook object as following.

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
var_dump($signed_request) ;

this is just to debug but u'll see that the printed array will contain many values that u won't get with js sdk for security reasons.

hope that helped better anyone who would need it, cz it seems this issue takes at the min 3 hours for everyone who runs into.